# "Standard" proof that open disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are connected?

Tags: analysis, connectedness

Homework for a complex analysis course asks me to prove as homework that open disks are connected. I do know a way to do this: open disks are convex, and an old exercise in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" guarantees that convex sets are connected. However, I suspect I'm missing the point a bit here.

Is there a quicker, more "first-principles" proof?

Comment: The simplest argument is probably to note that they’re path-connected: from any point in an open disk the radial line to the centre of the disk lies entirely within the disk, so a maximum of two such intervals are required to get from any point of the disk to any other.

Comment: As someone once described it to me, the proof that the surface of the sphere (and by a similar argument, a disc) is connected is that "all roads lead to Rome." Therefore it is path-connected, and thus connected since path-connectedness implies connectedness.

Answer (score 6):

A nice conceptual proof would be to notice that an open disk is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ - for instance, the map
$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2-y^2},\frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2}\right)$$
is such a homeomorphism. Then, choose your favorite proof that $\mathbb R^2$ is connected (or, better, that $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ is the product of two connected sets, and hence is connected).

Answer (score 3):

You just have to show, that for an open disk $D$ and $x,y\in D$, the connecting line

$$\{\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\ |\ \lambda\in [0,1]\}$$

is a subset of $D$ since this implies that $D$ is path connected.

This can be done using the triangle inequality: Let $z$ be the center of the disk, and $R$ it's radius. From $x,y\in D$ it follows, that

$$\|x-z\|<R,\ \|y-z\|< R$$

and therefore

$$\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-z\| =\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-(\lambda+1-\lambda)z\|\leq \lambda\|x-z\|+(1-\lambda)\|y-z\| < R$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x \mapsto \|x-x_0\|$ is a convex function, then set $B(x_0,r) = \{ x \mid \|x-x_0\| < r \}$ is convex. Convexity implies path connected (in fact, straight line connected) which implies connected.

Since you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you could note that
$B(x_0,r) = \phi([0,r) \times [0, 2 \pi))$,
where $\phi(r,\theta) = x_0+(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. Since $[0,r) \times [0, 2 \pi)$ is connected and $\phi$ is continuous, it follows that
$B(x_0,r)$ is connected.